# How to add value only within the range in vba

Tags: vba, excel

I'm new to VBA. I have the following code to add entry to cells in excel. 
The question here is how I can amend my code so that the add entry range will stop once C16 is reached? and next time when this code is executed, the starting range will be still from C5, replacing the value until C16.

I tried using for each loop but my itemTb.value will be the same for the whole range which I don't want it to be.

Please advise.

```
Private Sub addButton_Click()

    Range("C5").Select

    Do Until ActiveCell.Value = Empty
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Loop

    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 0).Value = Me.itemTb.Value

    Me.itemTb.Value = Empty
    Me.itemTb.SetFocus

End Sub
```

Comment: This seems quite a bit more elementary than your other questions. See http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/top-ten-excel-vba-control-structures.html

Comment: So does it go through successfully the first time and just fail the second?? Are you stopping at C16 every time or when you reach an empty cell?? What should the value of itemTb be changing based on (calculation logic) ?? Fairly unclear question as it is worded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this maybe? Store the range in a public variable (which should persist through runtime).

```
Public addRng as Range

Private Sub addButton_Click()

If addRng Is Nothing Then
    Set addRng = Range("C5")
Else
    Set addRng = addRng.Offset(1, 0)
    If addRng.Row > 16 Then
        'You may also want to unload the form, or use a message box
        ' to tell the user what is happening here
        Set addRng = Nothing
        Exit Sub
    End If
End If

addRng.Value = Me.TextBox1.Value

Me.itemTb.Value = Empty
Me.itemTb.SetFocus

End Sub
```